# Shellscript to put a date YYYYMMDD in the end of the filename

Tags: bash, shell

I'm creating a simple .sh and trying to put a date(yyyymmdd) in the end of my filename

```
today=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
file="/nas/backup_$today.sql"
echo $file
```

But when I print the name, this is the result:

```
.sql/backup_02_10_2022
```

How can I keep the ".sql" in the end of the name?

Comment: I'm not sure how this is what is being echoed. I tried on sh, bash, zsh, and ksh and they all print "/nas/backup_20220210.sql".

Comment: Your script has DOS line endings; `today` ends with a carriage return. `file` *does* end with `.sql` (well, `.sql\r`), but the carriage return moves the cursor while displaying the value.

Comment: See ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)